Why are new kernel versions not appearing in Fedora 40 Grub?
I upgraded from Fedora 38 to Fedora 40 more or less smoothly.
Yet, when new kernels are installed, the grub configuration is not updated.
The command grep vmlinuz /boot/grub2/grub.cfg shows
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.8-300.fc40.x86_64 root=UUID=0e08d465-d601-478f-be17-a2663626588c ro
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.8-100.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=0e08d465-d601-478f-be17-a2663626588c ro
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.3.12-200.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=0e08d465-d601-478f-be17-a2663626588c ro

but I do not have 6.3.12 installed, and ls /boot/loader/entries gives me
 vmlinuz-6.8.8-100.fc38.x86_64
 vmlinuz-6.8.8-300.fc40.x86_64
 vmlinuz-6.8.9-300.fc40.x86_64

agreeing with rpm -q kernel as well:
 kernel-6.8.8-100.fc38.x86_64
 kernel-6.8.8-300.fc40.x86_64
 kernel-6.8.9-300.fc40.x86_64

Yes, grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg restores the config, with the command grep vmlinuz /boot/grub2/grub.cfg now giving
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.9-300.fc40.x86_64 root=UUID=0e08d465-d601-478f-be17-a2663626588c ro
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.8-300.fc40.x86_64 root=UUID=0e08d465-d601-478f-be17-a2663626588c ro
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.8-100.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=0e08d465-d601-478f-be17-a2663626588c ro

but grub2-mkconfig is not supposed to be run each time a kernel is installed.
What is going on?

With the /boot/loader/entries in existence and up to date, there should be no mention of individual kernels in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg: instead, the configuration should be invoking the GRUB command blscfg which will cause GRUB to read /boot/loader/entries and use the information within. In other words, grep blscfg /boot/grub2/grub.cfg should return something like:
# The blscfg command parses the BootLoaderSpec files stored in /boot/loader/entries and
insmod blscfg
blscfg

If your grub2-mkconfig updates the list of kernels into /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, it means you must have an old version of the script /etc/grub.d/10_linux still active, or you must have added GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false to /etc/default/grub.
However, since RHEL 8 (and corresponding Fedora versions) the default kernel postinstall scripts now assume that blscfg is in use, and so the grub2-mkconfig doesn't need to be invoked after installing a new kernel, unless GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false is used in /etc/default/grub.
In RHEL/Fedora, kernel package post-transaction scripts will invoke /bin/kernel-install add <kernel version> ... on installation and /bin/kernel-install remove <kernel-version> ... on removal. The /bin/kernel-install will in turn invoke any scripts it finds in directories /etc/kernel/install.d/ and /usr/lib/kernel/install.d (with files in the former directory overriding any files with the same names in the latter) with similar add/remove and kernel version arguments.
The last script to execute on both installation and removal should be /usr/lib/kernel/install.d/99-grub-mkconfig.install: it runs grub2-mkconfig, but only if /etc/default/grub has GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG set to the exact string false. Any deviation will cause the script to assume the bootloader is capable of using /boot/loader/entries, and so the script will exit without doing anything.
If all this seems fine, look into your /etc/grub.d/ directory. Do you perhaps have a 10_linux.rpmnew or similar in there?
If you have such a file, backup your old (possibly customized) 10_linux file and replace it with the 10_linux.rpmnew (or similar) file, then run grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg one final time.
Apparently the /etc/grub.d/10_linux file might come from the grub2-tools package, so a dnf reinstall grub2-tools might be necessary if there is no 10_linux.rpmnew or similar file present.

I do not have any mention to blscfg in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.
Yes, I do have a 10_linux in /etc/grub.d/, but no 10_linux.rpmnew.
I did a dnf reinstall grub2-tools, and the 10_linux is identical to the one I had. In fact, the full /etc/grub.d/ is identical.
I also have a 40_custom, since I have several extra entries in my boot: double boot, Ventoy, USB boot, reboot, etc. But I do not know then how my system populates /boot/grub2/grub.cfg with the installed kernels.

I also have the lines insmod blscfg and blscfgin 10_linux. But not in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, even after a new grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.

Please see my edit.

Actually, it is the opposite: I have GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG="true" in /etc/default/grub.

Then that ensures grub2-mkconfig won't be executed on a kernel installation/removal. But you'll need to analyze what the 10_linux actually does for you: you could temporarily add set -x to its beginning and set +x to its end, to cause it display the commands it actually executes in fully expanded form. That should allow you to identify why the part that normally writes the insmod blscfg and blscfg lines gets skipped.

Sorry, I did not understand: Doesn't GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG="true" in /etc/default/grub should guarantee that grub2-mkconfig is executed? Anyway,  it is hard to debug 10_linux since it seems to work properly when grub2-mkconfig is executed. Yet, 10_linux has two IF that may fail to execute blscfg: x$GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG = "xtrue" (which seems to be fine), and NOT "x${BLS_POPULATE_MENU}" = "xtrue". And indeed I have export BLS_POPULATE_MENU="true" in my /etc/default/grub!! Maybe it is that??

The blscfg scheme means the bootloader should be able to build its menu from the fragments in /boot/loader/entries at boot time, so rebuilding grub.cfg at every kernel install/remove will be unnecessary. And so, if GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG is anything other than false, the /usr/lib/kernel/install.d/99-grub-mkconfig.install exits without doing anything at kernel install/removal time. But to decide whether to invoke the blscfg module or build a menu of kernels into grub.cfg, there is an another test in 10_linux... and apparently these two tests are not quite symmetrical.

I removed the export BLS_POPULATE_MENU="true" line from /etc/default/grub. Now grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg still works, yet instead of the explicit menu entries for each kernel, it reads insmod blscfg and blscfg. I guess that is the appropriate behaviour.

Just to confirm: Problem solved with the above modification. I originally added that line to rewrite the grub menu in a nicer way. Now I did this by editing the title tag in all files in /boot/loader/entries/* each time I run dnf update. Thanks!!
